# Is a node list is array?

Tags: javascript

So if you're answer is not then why we can use array foreach method with node list

And with html collection we can't use foreach method however  html collection is also not an array

Thanks

Comment: "*then why we can use array foreach method with node list*" because you use the [NodeList `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) not [the Array `.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: it's simple: a NodeList is a NodeList, a HTMLCollection is a HTMLCollection, and an Array is an Array -, but to add to the confusion:  a HTMLCollection is always a live list of Nodes- a NodeList can either be a static or a live list of Nodes ... and an Array remains an Array and can contains Nodes or not

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845)

Answer (score 3):

No, `NodeList` is not an array.

Any object may have a `forEach` method. [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is such an object: [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

[`HtmlCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) does *not* implement `forEach`, so you cannot use `forEach` on it.